# SQL select statement with random number

Tags: sql, random

I'm currently creating some type of quiz website.

My plan: Creating a random number in my sql statement to get a random question from my table.

E.g. every question have a numeric id -> creating random number (max number = records in my table) ->  select random question by id

I tried the followed statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE ID = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM question)) + 1);
```

My problem: 
Sometimes I got no result, sometimes I got two results and sometimes it worked as planed.

If I try the SELECT FLOOR etc. on it's own, the random number works perfectly.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance my friends!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have very many questions, you can simply do:

```
select q.*
from question q
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

If you have lots of questions, then reducing the number is important for performance.  Something like:

```
select q.*
from question q cross join
     (select count(*) from q) qq  
where rand() < 100 / q   -- get a sample of about 100
order by rand()
limit 1;
```